# How to import python script and pass arguments to the main function

Tags: python, python-2.7, arguments, parameter-passing, args

I have two python scripts. The main script calls generate.py which has a main function that takes 3 arguments from argsparse. What i am trying to do is , import generate.py in to main.py. Call the main function from generate.py but pass the three arguments in to this so that it can execute the main function with these arguments.

The three arguments are path , files and data.

Path is just a filepath to data
files is essentially the for loop looping through files in a directory
data is a folder with json files

So far my main.py script looks as follows. :

```
def get_json_location(username=os.getlogin()):
  first = "/Users/"
  last = "/Desktop/data-code/Testdata"
  result = first + username + last
return result


def get_config():
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument("-p", "--parameter-file", action="store", required=False)
  parser.add_argument("-e", "--export-data-file", action="store", required=False)
  parser.add_argument("-d", "--export-date", action="store", required=False)
  args = parser.parse_args()

  return [args.parameter_file, args.export_data_file, args.export_date]

  path, files, data = get_config()

  date = get_config()[2]
  yml_directory = os.listdir('yaml')
  yml_directory.remove('export_config.yaml')


def generate_json():
  with open('dates/' + date + '.json', 'w') as start:
  start.close()

  for yml in yml_directory :
  print("Running export for " + yml)


  # Here is the script that i am calling but i want to pass the parameters path , file and data_folder
  gen_json.main(path,files,data)



  if __name__ == '__main__':
  generate_json()
```

generate.py is as follows :

```
def main(get_config):
  cfg = get_config()[0] # json location
  data = get_config()[1] # export_agent_core_agent.yaml
  date = get_config()[2] # synthetic data folder - YYYY-MM-DD


json_location = cfg
json_database = data["config"]["database"]
json_collection = data["config"]["collection"]
json_path = "{0}/{1}{2}/{3}/{3}.json".format(json_location, date, json_database, json_collection)

def get_config():
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument("-p", "--parameter-file", action="store", required=True)
  parser.add_argument("-e", "--export-data-file", action="store", required=True)
  parser.add_argument("-d", "--export-date", action="store", required=True)
  args = parser.parse_args()

  return [args.parameter_file, funcs.read_config(args.export_data_file), args.export_date]


if __name__ == "__main__":
  logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
  main(get_config)
```

Comment: please correct the indention - this is not valid python code

Comment: Please indent your code properly (it's impossible to follow it as it is now). Also, please remove any code that isn't pertinent to _this_ question.

Comment: @thebjorn  Code has been indented  and removed code that isnt pertinent to this question

Comment: @JörgBeyer Code has been indented

Comment: are you sure, that this is real code? for example: "path, files, data = get_config()" in the "get_config" function is unreachable. You unconditioanlly "return" in the line above. Also please take a look at the "return" in "get_json_location"

Comment: Yes this is the correct code @JörgBeyer 

I have checked my code and its fine. get_json_location returns a file path

Comment: Please take another look at your code. What about the for-loop in generate_json? Or the return in the first function (get_json_location) ?

Comment: My code is fine. All i have not done is added in the imports @JörgBeyer

Comment: Why don't you refactor `main` in `generate.py` to take a list as input?  Then change the calling statements to first call `get_config` and then call `main` with the result.  Then you can call the `generate.py`'s `main` by `gen_json.main([path, files, data])`, i.e. explicitly sending a list.

Answer (score 1):

Think about refactoring your code!

To answer your question, you could pass a string from `main.py` to `gen_json.main('...')` and further to `gen_json.get_config('...')`. Argparse will evaluate that string, which needs to splitted into a list.
You are still able to call generate.py with command line parameters.

Please note that I removed **unneccessary/incorrect code/identation** to show how that could work in principle.

generate.py:

```
import argparse
import sys


def main(cliParams=None):
  cfg, data, date = get_config(cliParams)
  print (cfg, data, date)

  #json_location = cfg
  #json_database = data["config"]["database"]
  #json_collection = data["config"]["collection"]
  #json_path = "{0}/{1}{2}/{3}/{3}.json".format(json_location, date, json_database, json_collection)
  #print json_path

def get_config(cliParams=None):
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument("-p", "--parameter-file", action="store", required=True)
  parser.add_argument("-e", "--export-data-file", action="store", required=True)
  parser.add_argument("-d", "--export-date", action="store", required=True)

  if not cliParams:
    args = parser.parse_args()
  else:
    args = parser.parse_args(cliParams.split())
  #return [args.parameter_file, funcs.read_config(args.export_data_file), args.export_date]
  return [args.parameter_file, args.export_data_file, args.export_date]


if __name__ == "__main__":
  logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
  main()
```

main.py:

```
import os
import generate as gen_json

def generate_json():
  path = '/tmp/foo.yml'
  data = 'export_agent_core_agent.yaml'
  date = '2019-01-15'

  argParseString = '-p %s -e %s -d %s' % (path, data, date)
  gen_json.main(argParseString)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  generate_json()
```

Prints to stdout:

```
>>> /tmp/foo.yml export_agent_core_agent.yaml 2019-01-15
```